# How to update a pandas dataframe with an array of values, indexes, and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and would like to update specific values at known row and column indices.  I would like to do this without an explicit for loop.

For example:

```
import string                                                                                                                                  
import numpy as np                                                                                                                             
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                            
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10), index = range(10), columns = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:10])
```

I have arbitrary arrays of indexes, columns, and values that I would like to use to update df.  For example:

```
update_values = [0,-2,-3]                                                                                                                       
update_index = [3,5,7]                                                                                                                          
update_columns = ["d","g","i"]
```

I can loop over the arrays to update the original dataframe:

```
for i,j,v in zip(update_index, update_columns, update_values): 
    df.loc[i,j] = v
```

but would like to use a technique not involving an explicit for loop.

Comment: You have a list of values, and you want to use each item in the list to update your dataframe, you have to use a loop!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that's not actually how pandas works ;}

Comment: Ohh, Even I am learning pandas, could you point me to good resources which will help my understanding of pandas

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I believe constant training, official docs and stackoverflow is the best combo ;}

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the underlying `numpy` values

```
indexes = map(df.columns.get_loc, update_columns)
df.values[update_index, list(indexes)] = update_values
```

Comment: this answers my question.  thank you.  I do still wonder if there is anything in the pandas API to accomplish this without resorting to numpy and .values?

Comment: pandas' indexing is different from numpy's indexing. Take a look at the docs on indexing of both modules and you'll see the differences.. The lists you have are just perfect for numpy indexing and there is probably no faster way to do this other than just using the underlying numpy array

Answer (score 3):

try using `loc` which is used to specify the needed indexes and columns names loc[[index_names], [columns_names]]

```
df.loc[[3,5,7], ["d","g","i"]] = [0,-2,-3]
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does.  Those indices will return a `3x3` dataframe, and you are updating each row to those values, rather than the individual entries.